# Retrieve user roles but exclude default roles

Tags: user-roles

I am currently using the **[wp_roles()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_roles/)** function to retrieve all user roles available like this:

```
<?php
  foreach (wp_roles()->get_names() as $role) {
    echo translate_user_role( $role );
  }
?>
```

How would I retrieve an array/list of all *custom roles* that I've created without the default roles (Administrator, Editor, Subscriber, etc) included?

Comment: what does `translate_user_role` do? Wouldn't it be easier to use `__( ... )`, then you could use the standard core localisation system and the default roles would auto-translate

Comment: @TomJNowell Good point. I'll switch that part up. But how do I retrieve only custom roles and exclude default WordPress roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using a combination of the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function and the [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to retrieve all custom roles like this:

```
<?php

  function check_roles($userRole) {
    $default_roles = array('Administrator', 'Editor', 'Author', 'Contributor', 'Subscriber');
    if (!in_array($userRole, $default_roles)) {
      return $userRole;
    }
  }

  $all_roles = wp_roles()->get_names();
  $custom_roles = array_filter($all_roles, 'check_roles');

  foreach ($custom_roles as $role) {
    echo $role;
  }

?>
```